# .htaccess/Apache "Too many redirects" - Zend Framework Project

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework

I have an issue with the configuration of my .htaccess file in a project with Zend Framework 1. I can access to my login page but when i'm logging in i have a 301 error "Too many redirects" trying redirects me to a certain page.

This is my .htaccess file content :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And this is a part of my apache vhost conf with rewrite rules :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Have you an idea of where the problem is ?

Thanks for your time

**[EDIT]**

We are several devlopper on this project, i'm the only one who have this issue with the same config than the others. I don't understand why

Comment: Your htaccess and vhost rewrite rules do (almost) the same thing, you shouldn't have both. But neither perform any redirects so the problem is outside what you've posted in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not the creator of this project. So, I do not control the entire project. Could you please be more specific on where have i to looking for ? And what have i to search for ? Will the entire vhost config be helpful ?

Comment: I have try to deactivate .htaccess file then vhost rewrite rules but that have not solve the issue